# CASE Statement Value Checking

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that holds client addresses. A client can have more than one address records, and I need to determine how to return a value of either US, CAN or BOTH depending on whether they have an address in US or CAN, or if the have address's in both countries.

Am I on the right track, or completely wrong in thinking this?

```
SELECT A.CLNT_ID, CASE 
                WHEN (B.CNTRY_NAME = 'CANADA' AND B.CNTRY_NAME = 'UNITED STATES') THEN 'BOTH'
                WHEN (B.CNTRY_NAME = 'CANADA') THEN 'CAN'
                WHEN (B.CNTRY_NAME = 'UNITED STATES') THEN 'US'
              END
FROM CLNT_ADDR A
     ADDRESS B
WHERE A.CLNT_ID IN ('1111','2222','3333')
  WITH UR;
```

Comment: Well, does the query return the result you expected?

Comment: This line: `WHEN (B.CNTRY_NAME = 'CANADA' AND B.CNTRY_NAME = 'UNITED STATES')` says, "When `B.CNTRY_NAME` is `'CANADA'` **AND** `'UNITED STATES'` _at the same time_...  This can't be true, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I would assume the intent was to say `WHEN (B.CNTRY_NAME <> 'CANADA' AND B.CNTRY_NAME <> 'UNITED STATES')`, but this would better placed last as an `ELSE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use aggregation since a client can have multiple addresses. This uses `count` with `case` to achieve your results:

```
select c.clnt_id,
  case 
    when count(distinct a.cntry_name) = 2 then 'Both'
    when count(case when a.cntry_name = 'United States' then 1 end) > 0 then 'US'
    when count(case when a.cntry_name = 'Canada' then 1 end) > 0 then 'CA'
  end
from clnt_addr c
  left join address a on c.addr_id = a.addr_id
     and a.cntry_name in ('United States','Canada')
where c.clnt_id in ('1111','2222','3333')
group by c.clnt_id
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a93109/3)

Also please note, the `join` included.  I guessed that the joining field in both tables was called `addr_id`. Depending on your desired results, you may or may not need the `outer join`.